# Rstudio potential memory leak / background activity?

Tags: r, rstudio

I’m having a lot of trouble working with Rstudio on a new PC. I could not find a solution searching the web.

When Rstudio is on, it is constantly eating up memory until it becomes unworkable. If I work on an existing project, it takes half an hour to an hour to become impossible to work with. If I start a new project without loading any objects or packages, just writing scripts without even running them, it takes longer to reach that point, however, it still does.

When I first start the program, the Task Manager shows memory usage of 950-1000 MB already (sometimes larger), and as I work, it climbs up to 6000 MB at which point it is impossible to work with as every activity is delayed and 'stuck'. Just to compare, on my old PC while working on the program, the Task Manager shows 100-150 MB. When I click the "Memory Usage Report" within Rstudio, the "used by session" is very small, the "used by system" is almost at a maximum yet Rstudio is the only thing taking up they system memory on the PC.

Things I tried: installing older versions of both R and Rstudio, pausing my anti-virus program, changing compatibility mode, zoom on "100%". It feels like Rstudio is continuously running something in the background as the memory usage keeps growing (and quite quickly). But maybe it is something else entirely.

I am currently using the latest versions of R and Rstudio (4.1.2, and 2021.09.0-351), on a PC with processor Intel i7, x64 bit, RAM 16GM, Windows 10.

What should I look for at this point?

Comment: If you use R outside of RStudio, do you notice the same phenomenon?

Comment: Since I never work straight on RGui, I’m not sure what is considered ‘normal’ memory usage for basic/simple activities. However, I played with it a bit today and the memory usage rose from 90 MB to 810 MB very quickly, but then seemed to settle down as I was playing around with some files and scripts. Since it never reached the crazy usage-levels that RStudio does, the program didn’t slow down or get stuck (unless I wasn't on it long enough to 'get there')

Comment: This is not an issue I've ever heard of or run into. I would file an issue on the rstudio github repo to see what they suggest for debugging.

Comment: This sounds like what I have been experiencing for a few months. I am on RStudio 2021.09.1 Build 372 on Windows 11 Home version 21H2 (but I noticed the problem on RStudio 2021.09.0). 

(1) Do you have display scaling set to something other than 100% in Windows settings (mine is at 250%)? 

(2) Have you seen the memory used by “Desktop Window Manager” balloon over time? 

(3) Do some of the dialog boxes that pop up in RStudio sometimes have tiny text after the problem starts? (Check the message after a replace all)

(4) Did you submit an issue on Github for me to add details to?

Comment: I also get high memory usage on Rstudio 2021.09.2 Build 382. Windows 10

Comment: Small update: after trying every suggestion I could find, I finally called Dell. They replaced the motherboard and that solved the problem. It didn’t occur to me at first since my PC was brand new, but if nothing is working, it may not be an application/Windows/OS issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have suspected a leak somewhere in the graphics rendering pipeline because the Desktop Window Manager process sometimes also had its memory use grow until the system was unusable (though not recently), and some applications that use hardware acceleration (mostly MS Office) freeze or malfunction in strange ways (Excel always splitting views in the same spot, Word taking 12 seconds to show pasted text, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, there is several typical memory or CPU issues with Rstudio. In my answer, I explain how the Rstudio interface itself use memory and CPU, as soon as you open a project (e.g., when Rstudio show you some .Rmd files). The memory / CPU cost associated with the computation is not covered in my answer (i.e. when you have performance issues when executing a line of code = not covered).

When working on 'long' .Rmd files within Rstudio on Windows, the CPU and/or memory usage get sometimes very high and increases progressively (e.g., because of a process named 'Qtwebengineprocess'). To solve the problem caused by long Rmd files loaded within a Rstudio session, you should:

- pay attention to the process of Rstudio that consume memory, when scanning your code (i.e. disable or enable stuff in the 'Global options' menu of Rstudio). For example, **try to disable 'inline display'**(Tools => Global options => Rmarkdown => Show equation and image preview => Never). [This post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/qtwebengineprocess-100-cpu/43583/4) put me on this way to consider that memory / CPU leak are sometimes due to Rstudio itself, nor the data or the code.
- set up a bookdown project, in order to split your large Rmd files into several Rmd. See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/).

Bonus step, see if there is a conflict in some packages which are loaded with the command `tidyverse_conflicts()`,  but it's already a 'computing problem' (not covered here).